# Bootstrap bar no longer Following

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I've been working on my site and along the way the Bar stopped following on page scroll, and i cant figure out why. If anyone could help me figure out why it no longer follows on page scroll that would be great. Website: [chrisferreira.com](http://chrisferreira.com)

Thanks

Comment: When you say "Bar" i assume you are referring to the top navigation menu? Also are you using the Bootstrap Affix JS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the nav bar to follow you as you scroll down the page, you need to use this syntax instead for that div:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
```

The way it is currently, navbar-static will keep the nav appearing at the page top, and it will not scroll with you as you move down the page.